# plt.animation.ArtistAnimation IndexError and AttributeErrors

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw gif using `plt.animation.ArtistAnimation`
; but in my work, the error occurs

I've tried searching through google, but still not find some solution.
I don't know how to interpret the error message.
How should I understand the `ArtistAnimation` object?

My understanding is that I provide it with a list of `AxesImage` objects then it can generate an animation for me, then I can save it as `.gif`.

but things went wrong.

code as below:

```py
lst = [ (2330, 2018, 4), (2330, 2017, 4), (2330, 2016, 4) ]
ims = []


for i in range( len(lst) ):

    # get data from web

    co_id = str(lst[i][0])
    year = str(lst[i][1])
    season = str(lst[i][2])

    acct_dict = GetData( co_id, year, season ) # return a dictionary

    if i == 0:
        fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots( figsize=(10, 10) )
        PlorBars( ax1, acct_dict ) # plot figure 
        plt.title( co_id + '-' + year + '-' + season, loc='left')
        im = image.AxesImage( ax1, animated=True )
        ims.append( [im] )
#         print(ims)

    else:
        plt.figure( figsize=(10,10) )
        ax = plt.subplot( 111, sharey=ax1 )
        PlorBars( ax, acct_dict )
        plt.title( co_id + '-' + year + '-' + season, loc='left')
        im = image.AxesImage( ax, animated=True )
        ims.append( [im] )

# print(ims)
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(10, 10) )

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

ani.save('dynamic_images.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

the error message as below:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in saving(self, fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
    229         try:
--> 230             yield self
    231         finally:

D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in save(self, filename, writer, fps, dpi, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata, extra_anim, savefig_kwargs)
   1168                     # Clear the initial frame
-> 1169                     anim._init_draw()
   1170                 for data in zip(*[a.new_saved_frame_seq() for a in all_anim]):

D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in _init_draw(self)
   1543         for fig in figs:
-> 1544             fig.canvas.draw_idle()
   1545 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-267-53a6e022e605> in <module>
     35                                 repeat_delay=1000)
     36 
---> 37 ani.save('dynamic_images.gif', writer='pillow')
     38 plt.show()

D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in save(self, filename, writer, fps, dpi, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata, extra_anim, savefig_kwargs)
   1172                         # TODO: See if turning off blit is really necessary
   1173                         anim._draw_next_frame(d, blit=False)
-> 1174                     writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
   1175 
   1176         # Reconnect signal for first draw if necessary

D:\python3.7\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    128                 value = type()
    129             try:
--> 130                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    131             except StopIteration as exc:
    132                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in saving(self, fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)
    230             yield self
    231         finally:
--> 232             self.finish()
    233 
    234 

D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py in finish(self)
    579 
    580     def finish(self):
--> 581         self._frames[0].save(
    582             self._outfile, save_all=True, append_images=self._frames[1:],
    583             duration=int(1000 / self.fps))

IndexError: list index out of range
```